# Convert Word document of MS WORD 2003 To Tiff images

Tags: ms-word, document

I have a word document created using MS Office 2003.Now i developed a web application using ASP.net in which  i used a file upload control to upload word document files.My requirement is to convert the uploaded word document to tiff/jpg and displayed in iframe.please tell me the possible ways to achieve this.

Comment: which language are you using for web application ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have heard of Aspose, they have simple feature to achieve this.

Comment: yah i heard that one.But we have to purchase aspose.i require free tools.